# How to use include controller in test plan level - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a question in Jmeter that I want to resolve.
I am trying to create configuration package for each environment that I am working on.
for example:
1. Staging
2. QA
3. Production
I have configurations of each environment with its DB and servers.
I want to save then to test fragment and then with a single button to switch properties, just to select the configuration for each env.
The problem is that Jmeter not allow to add include installer at test plan level, how can I resolve it?
Provided a pic that demonstrates what I try to do
I want that **configuration** fragment (that saved all the properties of DB and server) will be at test plan level.
I have 3 fragments
1. configuration - My SQL + Vertica + Server of QA ENV
2. Configuration Prod - My SQL + Vertica + Server of production ENV
3. Configuration Stg - My SQL + Vertica + Server of staging ENV

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give specific parameters in configuration that need to be changed?

Comment: Q: "How to use include controller in test plan level"; A: you can't. But now try to think about what you are trying to achieve instead of how you planned to achieve it. As @user7294900 said, question could be answerable if you specified exactly how configs are different, and at which point you want to switch them (e.g. before execution, during execution, etc.

Comment: I will try to be more specific, I am trying to build framework for other QA, and I want to achieve that each one of them can select on which Environment to test. the difference is in the servers name, IP, database name and Ip, I would like to create a 3 properties files, so If production selected all the specifications will take effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to have 3 separate configurations, one will be sufficient. Example setup:

- Add [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) element to the top of Test Plan
- Define your variable there using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

  [image]
- Create file `qa.properties` with the following line:

  ```
  foo=bar
  ```
- Create file `stag.properties` with the following line:

  ```
  foo=baz
  ```
- If you run your JMeter test like:

  ```
  jmeter -q qa.properties -t test.jmx
  ```

  `${foo}` variable value will be `bar`
- If you run your JMeter test like:

  ```
  jmeter -q stag.properties -t test.jmx
  ```

  `${foo}` variable value will be `baz`

I believe this way is way more faster, convenient and flexible. Check out [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) article for more information if needed